# Why does TFS 2017 Update 1 not recognize a default value as a default in a Task Group?

Tags: tfs

I've created a Task that I converted to a Task Group (*and why TFS won't allow you JUST to create a Task group is still beyond me, but I digress*).

All the parameters in this task have default values. However the one I really care about is the third one (highlighted)

[image: Task Group Definition]

My understanding was that I could leave that blank when I consume the task in a build definition. However this is what I get when I leave it blank:

[image: Task Group in use with warning about lack of value]

In addition I'm unable to save this build definitition until I've entered a value. It's not a show stopper by any means and it's really easy to enter the same value again. I'm just perplexed as to why it's doing this. Have I missed a new definition of the word ***Default***?

Answer (score 0):

Check the first item of [how the task group is created](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/library/task-groups):

Ensure that all of the tasks you want to include in a task group have their parameters defined as variables, such as $(MyVariable), where you want to be able to configure these parameters when you use the task group. Variables used in the tasks are automatically extracted and converted into parameters for the task group. **Values of these configuration variables will be converted into default values for the task group.**

> If you specify a value (instead of a variable) for a parameter, that
>   value becomes a fixed parameter value and cannot be exposed as a
>   parameter to the task group. Parameters of the encapsulated tasks for
>   which you specified a value (instead of a variable), or you didn't
>   provide a value for, are not configurable in the task group when added
>   to a build or release definition.